# How to make an array with class types and change the html ids?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to change `#changecolor1, 2, 3, 4...` to a "class" and use the class values 1 2 3 4.
How can I do it with an array?

I tried:

```
<script>
    var color=["text-pink","text-pink4","text-pink9"];

    var y= document.createAttribute("class");
    y.value=(color[0])     
    var x = document.getElementById("changecolor");
    x.setAttributeNode(y);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property `className`

```
document.getElementById("changecolor").className = color[0];
```

If you have multiple elements - if I understand it right starting from `#changecolor1`, you can use a loop

```
for (var i = 0; i<color.length;i++) {
    var x = i + 1;
    document.getElementById('changecolor' + x).className = color[i];
}
```

Note that this will break if there are too few elements with the id. To avoid this, you could add a check if the element exists.

```
for (var i = 0; i<color.length;i++) {
    var x = i + 1;
    var el = document.getElementById('changecolor' + x);
    if (el) el.className = color[i];
}
```